# Has RN disabled style prop checking in 0.57.3?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Some time back, whenever I used to write `<Component styles={{...}}/>`
and React used to throw an error, helpfully saying that perhaps I meant style and not styles.

Recently, I wasted a lot of time in figuring out why a certain Text component was not receiving any styles and it turned out that instead of style, I used styles.

My question is, how to enable those errors again?

Answer (score 0):

After looking for such warnings in the React & React Native source code, here is what I found.

The function responsible of these warnings is `throwOnStylesProp`. It is defined in [NativeMethodsMixinUtils.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.5.2/packages/react-native-renderer/src/NativeMethodsMixinUtils.js#L48-L66)  and used in [NativeMethodsMixin.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.5.2/packages/react-native-renderer/src/NativeMethodsMixin.js#L200-L211).

To be able to see these warnings:

1. You need to be on __DEV__ environment (debug config);
2. The component on which you pass **`styles`** has to use the `NativeMethodsMixin`.

Based on [these search results](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?q=NativeMethodsMixin), it seems like only some specific RN components uses that Mixin (`TextInput`, `TouchableHighlight`, `TouchableOpacity`).

Comment: What are the minimum number of steps needed to ensure that a specific (or all) component uses that mixin. How do we make a component use that mixin. I read the code, but since I am new with React, some pointers would be appreciated.